# What is the time format 'MMMMMMMSS'?

Tags: c#, datetime

When processing a file from a telecom company, I came across this in the specifications :

[image]

When reading in that data, how can I convert that format to something usable in c# ?  I have no idea what `MMMMMMMMSS` format is !!

Comment: would you not assume minutes and seconds?   Does it have leading zeros?

Comment: the actual bytes look like  `0125      `   yes, including those 6 spaces lol

Comment: Look at this document: http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/d01a/tred/tred2379.htm
Maybe it will be helpful for you, e.g.: 405   MMMMSS = Time without hours: m=minutes, s=seconds.

Comment: Ask telecom company... It can mean anything.

Comment: @Bindrid - it turns out it was actually supposed to be 7 bytes in the format `MMMMSST` where `MMMM` is minutes left padded with 0's, `SS` for seconds, and `T` for tenths of a second.  Fail doc!   You guess was my first one as well, but the position on the line and formatting suggestion weren't making sense.

Comment: @PawelMaga - your format and Bindrid's thought process came very close. I had to kind of hash through a line that looks like this : `010101161225105198534453   106479071981000125         221018000020002        141 ` to hack out the data in a manner that makes sense.  Worst CDR format I have ever seen -.-  (just so you know, the origin and destination number are fragmented into multiple parts, and date/time duration, cost, origin, destination, etc are in that mess.

Answer (score 2):

The only logical explanation I can think of is the following:

Since this is a call duration representation, let's say that a call duration was `10:10:5`. I assume they want to represent this in minutes and seconds only. Hence *considering the given format*, it would be represented like this: `61005` which is `610` minutes and `5` seconds, then the 5 remaining bytes can be filled with trailing zeros, or with space characters (since you mentioned that's what they used to represent a value).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found the problem.  The starting byte as outlined in the specification was incorrect. The format itself is still "best guess"

Comment: Turns out the specification is wrong.  The total bytes was actually 7, and the first 4 are `minutes` left padded with `0`, followed by 2 digits for seconds, and 1 digit for the 10ths of a second -.-

Answer (score -1):

I would expect each of these to be zero-padded. Regardless, Split the last two characters off to derive seconds and cents, respectively.  The first 8 characters represent minutes and dollars.  A one minute (exactly) call would be 7 zeros followed by a 1 followed by two zeros.  A ten minute and ten second call would be 6 zeros followed by 1010.

Comment: Do you have any source to back this up?

Comment: This is incorrect as the 10 bytes representing duration is 4 numbers followed by 6 spaces.